# Integer: Why does it work on Linux and not on Windows

Tags: c

I have a big Problem. I am a beginner in C, my task is to program a "robot" which is circling my room (theoretically). I tried it with this method:
index = 0;
if you type in "yes" it will add 1 on the index, if you answer with "no" or something else it just print something. If index >= 4 it will print something and stop the program.

I compiled it on my Raspberry PI 4 with cc and it works totaly fine but if i use Code Blocks (i think it uses GCC) it will set the Integer to 115 (if i type in yes, otherwise it will be 0) and add 1 more to 116, i absolutly dont know why. But i think its a Problem with the compiler. How can solve this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
void main()
{
char wall[2];
int index;
index = 0;
 while(wall[0] == '\0'){ // Check if wall[0] is empty

        printf("Go!\n");
        printf("Is the Wall already there?\n");
        printf("Number: %i\n", index);
        scanf("%s", wall);

      if(strcmp(wall, "yes") == 0){
          printf("Turn!\n");
          index++;
          if(index >= 4){
              printf("You have circled the room once %i!\n", index);
              exit(0);
          }
      }
      else if(strcmp(wall, "no")  == 0){
          printf("Sad... go on\n");
      }
      else {
            index++;
          printf("You can answer only with yes or no!\n");
      }
      wall[0] = '\0';
}
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s", wall);` inputting anything there longer than a single character leads to _undefined behavior_. Ensure that the buffer is big enough to take the input.

Comment: When you do `while(wall[0] == '\0')` the first time, the `wall` is uninitialized. That's UB.

Comment: If `strcmp(wall, "yes") == 0` then you have broken something, or maybe not.

Comment: The problem is *almost never* with the compiler.

Comment: and how do i fix this?

Comment: but why does it work on my Raspberry PI (Rasbian)

Comment: With a more generous array say `char wall[20];` and input length restriction: `scanf("%19s", wall);` At the least `"Yes"` needs 4 elements, and maybe you'll need longer responses.

Comment: "why does it work?" ... purely **bad luck**, remember: undefined behaviour can [appear to] do what you expect, but it's still wrong

Comment: ok i tried wall[20] my program doesnt work anymore it returned 8 (0x8)

Comment: _"problem with the compiler"_ - almost never the case.  Occam's Razor applies.  A tool that works for thousands of developers doesn't work for you - you think?

Comment: Sorry, did you fix what [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65725389/integer-why-does-it-work-on-linux-and-not-on-windows#comment116207033_65725389) said? I meant `char wall[20] = "";`

Comment: Weather Vane, i did it and it worked. Last Question the index is going +1 too if i type in no. If i type in something other it does nothing how it should

Comment: @TomKönig It is not clear what your new problem is.  I ran the code with the suggested changes and it is fine (or at least it runs).  The comments section is not for asking run-on questions (it is also not for posting answers either but people will do that if they think the question too trivial to warrant one) , post a new question with the new code.  However if you enter something other than yes/no, index is still incremented, but you are using index to indicate the number of walls.  That might be a semantic error - seems odd.

Answer (score 0):

my mistake was to use char wall[2] its to small for words like yes, i just changed it to

```
char wall[20]
```

Answer (score -1):

How much space is there in `char wall[2]`, and how much space do you think you need for the string `yes`, including the zero byte to mark the string’s end?

Comment: really i dont know something with space, i thought its a String, i got this from my teacher

Comment: I see that these are intended as rhetorical questions, but even so, they do not constitute an answer.

Comment: @TomKönig : It is not that hard to understand.  `wall[2]` is an array of _two_ characters. `"yes"` is a string of three characters plus a terminator.  As such `wall` can hold a string of just one character.  Perhaps your teacher expected y/n answers rather then yes/no?  Dangerous code nonetheless.